# What's the difference between these async method declarations?

Tags: javascript, async-await

What happens under the hood?

```
const facade = {
    // A:
    doSomething: async () => await delegatedFunction(),
    // B:
    doSomething: async () => delegatedFunction(),
    // C:
    doSomething: () => delegatedFunction(),
    // D:
    doSomething: delegatedFunction,
}

async function delegatedFunction() {}
```

Comment: In this case it's totally irrelevant, they're all functions returning a promise.

Comment: I'd prefer D, when it's equivalent, because it introduces zero overhead. It also enables arguments to be passed in without effort.

Comment: All apart from D are creating an extra function, for no extra benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First three functions bind the parameters for `delegatedFunction`. You can't pass any values to it (others than the one specified in the function call).

Third function is also the only non-async function (it's still async though, just not an async function object). It has some differences but it might not matter to you in the end.

For example:

```
(async () => 1).constructor !== (() => 1).constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

`async await` is an abstraction for Javascript promises.
There is no possible clear answer here, as you're not writing the body of the `delegatedFunction`.

A: `facade.doSomething()` will return the **result** of calling the `delegatedFunction`

B, C, and D: will return a promise, no matter what you're returning from `delegatedFunction`

If you want more details, you need to write a better question

Comment: Thanks, I think A) returning the result is what makes the usage questionable for me, as it sounds i can't use it as a promise higher up, right? So would for instance `await Promise.all([facade.doSomethingA(param), ..])` work as expected, or would it evaluate right away since I am not passing a promise but a value to `Promise.all`